# what is the best way to win: every 1000 submission will win

Tags: probability

I have a question about probability.

The game is like this:

> Every $1000$th submission will win, but the players don't know how many
>   submissions were made before.

Is it better for a player to throw all of his $100$ credits in one time or is it better to throw one then wait then submit the next... and so on?

Comment: baf, would you look at my edit and see if it accurately represents what you were trying to write?

Comment: yes it is, thank you. my english is not so good

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that you submit, and submit again, and again, with a random and very large number of other people playing between your submissions. Although the lottery increments its number by $1$ each time a single bet is made, the numbers on the tickets that you buy electronically vary in totally unpredictable ways. Then the probability you win on any one play is $\frac{1}{1000}$. So the probability you do not win on that play is $1-\frac{1}{1000}$. Thus, by the assumption of independence, the probability that you lose $100$ times in a row is
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{1000}\right)^{100}.$$
This is about $0.9047921$. So the probability you win *at least once* is about $1-0.9047921$, which is about $0.0952079$.

If you "throw in" all at once, meaning I assume that you are getting $100$ *consecutively* numbered tickets, the probability you win is $\frac{100}{1000}$, that is, $0.10$, somewhat higher than $0.0952079$. But playing in scattered fashion gives the possibility of winning more than once, while with the "throw in" this is not possible.

If "winning" means winning say $400$ dollars, then the *expected* (mean) amount of money that you win will be the same with *either* strategy. Roughly speaking the small lowering of the probability of winning with the scattered play strategy is exactly compensated for, in the sense of *expected* winnings, by the possibility of winning twice, or even more often.

Answer (score 2):

if you buy $n$ lots at random times then each will have $1$ in $1000$ chance of winning

but if you buy one and you lose then the next lot will have $1$ in $999$ chance to be the winning lot if you lose again then it's 1 in 998 etc.

but if you buy them in bulk (i.e. buy the next lot before you know if you won with the last) then it's back to $1$ in $1000$ for each